# Windows 10 refuses to unblock a file, how do I fix this?

Tags: windows-10, python

I recently upgraded my version of Python to the latest version, but now Windows is blocking pip.exe and preventing me from installing new packages.

I keep getting Windows Security notifications saying `This content is blocked` whenever I try to interact with pip. The pop-ups give me the option to unblock, and every time they appear I click it, but when I go to run the program the pop-up just appears again.

When I right-click pip.exe to view its properties, the properties box doesn't even list the file as blocked. I've tried unblock-file in PowerShell. I've even tried manually setting the zone identifier to 0 (the file didn't even have a zone identifier to begin with), but nothing works.

The only workaround so far is by using `python -m pip` and bypassing having to directly interact with pip.exe, but I still want to unblock pip.exe itself.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all of Windows Security Center (e.g. firewall, antivirus, etc.)? Have you tried running Python and/or pip  as an administrator (in all combinations of the 2 - e.g. Python as admin, pip as not, Python as not, pip as admin, Python and pip as admin)? There are just some shots in the dark.

Comment: I added Python's program folder as an exception to Windows Security and that seems to have worked. I was already running pip as administrator.

Comment: It was my hope to arrive at the right exception after navigating various troubleshooting methods. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: @FrederickEason - You should submit an answer instead of editing an answer into your question

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, I have.

Answer (score 2):

Adding Python's program folder to the exceptions list in Windows Security now allows me to run pip.exe fine.